# Custom view helper in Ember.js, "You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process"

Tags: ember.js

I want to bind my custom view's class to a controller property.

<sup>[javascript]</sup>

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  headerClass: "a"
});

App.TestHeaderView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNames: ["test-header"],
  classNameBindings: ["headerClass"],
  headerClass: null,
  templateName: "views/test-header"
});
```

<sup>[templates]</sup>

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{view App.TestHeaderView text="view helper" headerClass=controller.headerClass }}
    <hr />
    {{input value=headerClass}}   
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="views/test-header">
    <small>{{view.text}}</small>
  </script>
```

The result is predictable: everything works. I can enter the class name in the text box and see it reflected in the view.

So now I want to extend this and add my own helper that wraps the `{{view}}` call.

<sup>[javascript]</sup>

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("test-header", function (options) {
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.TestHeaderView, options);
});
```

<sup>[templates]</sup>

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{test-header text="custom helper" headerClass=controller.headerClass}}
  </script>
```

Nothing special right? Except, I keep getting this:

`Uncaught Error: You can't use appendChild outside of the rendering process`

For full working jsbin, [click here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jejutakaguwu/1/edit).

It seems this should work. I'm just wrapping the ember's view helper pretty much exactly. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

The trick is in the `contexts` array in the options hash.

When you call `{{view App.MyView}}` from handlebars, Ember's view helper gets in its `options.contexts` array the "context" in which it should search for "App.MyView" property - usually the current controller. In this case, "App.MyView" will be resolved regardless of the context, but I guess Ember keeps the context around and uses it to resolve bound properties.

When I called:

```
{{test-header text="custom helper" headerClass=controller.headerClass}}
```

there was no first argument from which to draw the context. Therefore, when I passed the call along to the view helper:

```
return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.TestHeaderView, options);
```

... there was no context passed along in the `options.contexts` array.

The way I fixed this is:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper("test-header", function (options) {
  options.contexts = [this].concat(options.contexts);
  return Ember.Handlebars.helpers.view.call(this, App.TestHeaderView, options);
});
```

IMO Ember should do a better job here. They should either figure out a context from reference, or throw an error (a preferred option).